# Browser plugin to import REST Web Services WADL file and provide invocation page

Tags: web-services, rest, browser-plugin, wadl

Looking for a Browser plugin that can parse a REST Web Services wadl file and present a page listing all the services and a way to invoke any of the services setting appropriate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try Timboo.com They have about 2,000 different entries for various API Methods as "choreos" for choreographies, and you might find yours already there or you could import your defs into their system.  Even DreamFactory.com or apigee.com have similar features.   Which service are you interested in?  Even Cloud9.com can support most of what you need.  Or Node.js or Modulus.com  Good luck.